# Editor/ Reviewer Info in answers - Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

The flag button in answers of the new Android app is going off screen. The entire answer section seems to be entirely to the right.

[image]

**Update** as asked overflow works but the reviewer's pic seems cut and the **edited in x minutes** has no space.

[image]

- Android OS Version:  5.1
- App Version: 1.0

Comment: Is the horizontal bar with Edit / Share / Flag scrollable for you? It's supposed to let you scroll left/right to access the overflow items. I think I'll be replacing that with a non-scrolling version that moves the overflow items into a "..." button.

Comment: Yes overflow seems to work.. Updated the issue. The reviewer name and pic is cut

Comment: Got it, I see that happening on a smaller width device too. I'll post an answer on this question once I've made the user badges go ontop of each other on smaller screens, not next to each other.

Comment: Ok..thanks for the quick response

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi in version 1.0.1 I do see that both badges are seen fully side by side although not on top of each other as you have commented. Is this completed?

Comment: as of version 1.0.1 the app does a check each time it renders the user badges to see if it can fit them horizontally, if so it displays them horizontally, else it puts them on top of each other. This way it works consistently on all smaller width devices, or cases with people with long display names.